# Swagger Support in Hippo REST API

Tags: swagger, hippocms

We have followed the steps what mentioned in the below document.

https://www.onehippo.org/labs/integrating-swagger-with-hippo-cms-restful-resources.html

After configuring all steps, we are getting 404 for Rest API-DOC and couldn't move further.
URL: http://localhost:8080/site/rest/api-docs

**Can someone help here to take this forward?**

**Logging Information:**

```
 4.08.2018 20:48:45 WARN  ajp-nio-8009-exec-9 [JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest:166] No root resource matching request path /site/rest/api-doc has been found, Relative Path: /api-doc. Please enable FINE/TRACE log level for more details.
    14.08.2018 20:48:45 INFO  ajp-nio-8009-exec-9 [DiagnosticReportingValve.logDiagnosticSummary:44] Diagnostic Summary:
    - HstDelegateeFilterBean (22ms): {request=Request{ method='GET', scheme='https', host='localhost', requestURI='/site/rest/api-doc', queryString='null'}}
```

Comment: There isn't really enough information here to give advice. The error is that the endpoint can't be found. Also note that the article referenced is a lab (a blogpost) and not official documentation. See https://www.onehippo.org/library/enterprise/services-features/content-hal-api/content-hal-api.html and https://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/spa-plus/page-model-api/swagger-api-documentation.html

Comment: are you using https on purpose or was just overlooked?

Comment: @smuco  The https was overlooked. have edited that post.

Comment: @JasperFloor What we have done is we have introduced some new APIs in Site war to perform the CURD operation. For that APIs we have to make the swagger doc. The new class file has added in site war and have included all annotation there. The swagger dependency , Mounting and other swagger related setup has been included but we didn't get the swagger details in http://localhost:8080/site/rest/api-docs path.  Kindly help us here and feel free to revert us if you need more clarity...

Comment: I honestly don't know what it could be. Check out the links I sent previously, there is some talk of Swagger there. Without taking a look in your project I can't say much more, and that is something you will need to contact formal support for. Maybe someone else has more experience with Swagger and can help directly.

Comment: @Ashok, Have you found a solution to the problem here ? I am facing the same issue.